# Find time difference between start status and end status with pause status

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I have a set of records in a table , the table contains `problemid, starttime, endtime, status`.

- If the problem starts then the status become `He010`
- If the problem ends then the status become `He006`
- If the problem is paused then the status `Hs014`
- If the pause is not found then I will easily get the total time between `starttime` and `endtime`

Like this:

```
declare @StartDate datetime, @EndDate datetime

select @StartDate = '2015-11-02 17:17:38.000',@EndDate='2015-11-02 17:17:49.000'

select convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s, @startDate, @EndDate)/3600) +':'+
       convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s, @startDate, @EndDate)%3600/60) +':'+
       convert(varchar(5),(DateDiff(s, @startDate, @EndDate)%60)) as [hh:mm:ss]
```

But I can't get is pause is present.

If pause is present I want to do like this,

```
Start + Pause then
pause + complete = total time
```

[image: Table Data]

How can I do this, 
suggest me to get a solution.

Comment: sample data + expected resultset.

Comment: what is exactly that you want to do? what do you mean by `If pause is present I want to do like this,

Start + Pause then
pause + complete = total time`

Comment: I want to calculate total time for that problemID

Comment: looks like the second row is the start. does it mean it was in that status for 3 hours? when you want to calculate total time, does it mean you want to calculate the time the problemid was in the status of `He010`, `He006` and `Hs014`??

Comment: Yes second row is start , third row is pause , then again fourth row is start then fifth row is complete so 15:35:10 +  0:0:14

Comment: It seems as though you only need to calculate the sum of the difference between starttime and finishtime of each of the HE010 records? Is that correct?  Please clarify your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the total time the user was taking the test (sum of difference between HE010 start and end times, as the other events are not needed to calculate this), then you can simply do something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, StartTime, FinishTime))
FROM tbl33997393
WHERE ProblemID = 'P1234' 
GROUP BY ProblemID
```